ms graph call to list notebooks failing with "InvalidAuthenticationToken"
the following code fails with "InvalidAuthenticationToken"
{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."

I'm sure I've got the app registration in azure ad correct.
import urllib.parse
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.utils.dump import dump_all

tenant_id = "..."
client_secret = "..."
client_id = ".."
scope = "api://<guidfromzurehere/.default"

url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
data = {
    "client_id": client_id,
    "scope": scope,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
print(dump_all(r).decode('utf8'))
print(r.json()['access_token'])

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myemailaddress/onenote/notebooks"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + r.json()['access_token']}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(dump_all(r).decode('utf8'))

Is my scope wrong?  I've tried a scope of "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", but the I get a license error. Suggestions?

Solved this after much trial and error leading other error messages leading me to find this and this.
In the end I got a solution to work with no licensing using the OAuth Code Grant flow as required by delegated permissions and using the sign in of /consumers rather than tenant id as most of the GraphAPI docs say.

While the information in your links may solve your issue, answers that rely heavily on links are discouraged for these reasons. Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained, with the minimum amount of code and instructions required to demonstrate how it works. Thanks
